# Use lapply() to find percentages of factor variables

Tags: r, lapply, reshape2, split-apply-combine

I have a data frame that consists of 4 columns that represent questions, and each column as 4 levels that represent responses.

```
  Q1 Q2
1  A  A
2  A  B
3  B  B
4  C  C
5  D  D
```

And I'd like to derive a `data.frame` such as this:

```
   question response percent
1       Q2        A     0.2
2       Q2        B     0.4
3       Q2        C     0.2
4       Q2        D     0.2
5       Q1        A     0.4
6       Q1        B     0.2
7       Q1        C     0.2
8       Q1        D     0.2
```

So far, I've been achieving this with a `for` loop, but my scripts are riddled with `for` loops so I'd like to achieve this using functions in `reshape2` or with `lapply`. For instance this code is a lot cleaner than a `for` loop but still not quite what I'm looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I've got so far:

```
lapply(lapply(df, summary), function(x) x/sum(x))
```

**EDIT:** Including example of data frame per request. I was originally afraid it would take up too much space since the level labels are so long, so I shortened them.

```
dput(df[1:4,])
structure(list(Q1 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("1.A", 
    "1.B", "1.C", "1.D"), class = "factor"), 
    Q2 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("2.A","2.B",
    "2.C", "2.D"), class = "factor"), 
    Q3 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("3.A","3.B",
    "3.C","3.D"), class = "factor"), 
    Q4 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("4.A","4.B", 
    "4.C","4.D")), 
    .Names = c("Q1.pre", "Q2.pre", "Q3.pre", "Q4.pre"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), 
    class = "data.frame")
```

I've found that a combination of Lafortune and user20650's responses has given me almost exactly what I've been looking for:

```
melt(sapply(df, function(x) prop.table(table(x))))
```

However there's one problem. At the `sapply` level, the `dimnames` are the same as the label names of the levels for Q1, and so after performing `melt` the output of `sapply`, the Var1 column is just a repetition of Q1s levels, whereas I'd like Var1 to have Q1's levels in the Q1 rows, Q2's levels in the Q2 rows, etc. I found a workaround by pulling the `levels` of all of the columns into a separate variable `qnames` *before* performing any operations on `df` like so:

```
qnames = melt(sapply(df, levels))
qnames = qnames[ ,3]
melt(sapply(df, function(x) prop.table(table(x))))
df = cbind(qnames, df)
```

Which is exactly the result I need. I'm interested to see if there is a way to achieve this without the extra `sapply` and `cbind`, so I'll leave the question open a little longer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: **Please post a reproducible example.** Use `dput()` on your dataframe and give us e.g. the top-20 rows

Comment: This is just an aggregation. Read about [tag:split-apply-combine], dplyr and data.table. Do a `group_by(question)`.

Comment: (by the way, `percent` should be called `fraction`, unless you multiply it by 100 in your function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-liner using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table) # 1.9.5+
dt<-data.table(Q1=c("A","A","B","C","D"),
               Q2=c("A","B","B","C","D"))

rbindlist(lapply(
  names(dt),
  function(x)dt[,.N/nrow(dt),by=x
                ][,.(question=x,response=get(x),percent=V1)]))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is incredibly efficient code! However, I prefer to use the `sapply` and `lapply` functions because I think the code is more transparent and easier to reproduce (I definitely need to read up on data.table package).

Comment: @Killerfurbies you'll notice the crux of my code is indeed `lapply`. If you want a great resource for starting `data.table`, check out the Getting Started vignettes on their github page, they're crystal clear ways to dig in. And the payoff to learning `data.table`, I must add, is IMO immense.

Comment: I've returned to your code and am trying to implement it in a custom function, but I keep receiving the error `Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'`. I've been scouring stackoverflow and I believe it has to do with the frame in which the `j` expression, or `by`, is evaluated. Do you have any ideas as to how to solve this?

Comment: That's because the `.(` alias is new to the development version of `data.table`, see the [GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) for instructions on installing the latest updates. If you don't feel like doing that (I recommend it because there are all sorts of goodies in 1.9.5), you can replace `.(question...` with `list(quesion...`

Comment: Ah, I was indeed using an older version of `data.table`. Now, after replacing `.(` with `list(`, I'm getting the error `Error in get(x) : object 'Q1' not found`. Again, this is only in the personal function that it happens, not when I run the same code in the console. Thanks for your help @MichaelChirico!

Comment: @Killerfurbies strange. Code still works for me. Could you print the output of `names(dt)`?

Comment: This is the output of `print(names(dt))` immediately before your code:
`[1] "Q1" "Q2" "Q3" "Q4"`
`Error in get(x) : object 'Q1' not found`
Again, it works perfectly fine when I enter the code directly into the console, it's just within my function that it returns this error.  I often run into problems when manipulating `data.table` objects within functions, usually when modifying columns by reference. But that can be solved by enclosing the `LHS` in parentheses. Perhaps this deserves a new thread...

Answer (score 2):

```
library(reshape2)
indx <- lapply(df, function(x) prop.table(table(x)))
out <- melt(do.call(rbind, indx))
out <- out[order(out$Var1, decreasing=TRUE),];rownames(out) <- NULL
#   Var1 Var2 value
# 1   Q2    A   0.2
# 2   Q2    B   0.4
# 3   Q2    C   0.2
# 4   Q2    D   0.2
# 5   Q1    A   0.4
# 6   Q1    B   0.2
# 7   Q1    C   0.2
# 8   Q1    D   0.2
```

You can use `lapply` and `reshape2`, but a good function to have is `prop.table`. When it wraps the `table` function, it will do the percentage for you. We create a proportion table for each column using `lapply` and then combine them with the always faithful `do.call(rbind, lst)`. The last line is for the 'look'.

Comment: if you use `sapply` you can avoid the `do.call` stuff ... ie `melt(sapply(dat, function(x) prop.table(table(x))))`

Comment: Thank you. Always great to optimize!

Comment: No probs... the lapply / do.call might actually be faster ... but the sapply imo is more readable here

Comment: I can't test right now (SO mobile), but I think one function is usually better than two.

Comment: I agree with greater readability for `sapply` - thanks, that was the route I pursued.